# Unexpected behaviour with KnockoutJS Keypress event on input

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

I have an event binding on an input of type search, this is in order to fire a search off to the server side and populate the list as the user is typing.

That part is fine and I have established a skeleton example using pure javascript, when it came time to integrate into knockout, I ran into a curious issue.

I have in my HTML the standard binding:

```
<input data-bind="event:{keypress:ring}" type="text" />
```

For this example my ring function will simple log something when the key is pressed :

```
ring: function (event) {
            this.triggered(this.triggered() + 1);
            var msg = "Keypress binding called " + this.triggered() + " time(s).";
                    console.log(msg);
                }
```

That's all normal and no problem with that..

**The problem is the input value/string is not being updated.. It simply stays blank as if I have not pressed anything.**

Im curious am I missing some sort of default forwarding I am supposed to do ? Is this expected behaviour ? Seems a little strange to me.

A working example is here : [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szcuyq13/)

As you type into the input, nothing happens apart from my `ring` function.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you make a simplified JSFiddle of your problem? Do you need to be using KnockOut? Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return true from your event handler function to allow the default action to take place on the input.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/szcuyq13/1/

```
    ring: function (event) {
        this.triggered(this.triggered() + 1);
        var msg = "Keypress binding called " + this.triggered() + " time(s).";
        console.log(msg);
        return true;
    }
```

In other words, this is exactly as you guessed: you just need to add a little bit more to ensure the 'default forwarding' happens as you expect. KO by default prevents the default action in a bound event handler and by returning true you are requesting that default action to complete. It's described here, under the heading Note 3:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

That note also explains why KO does this, which makes sense when you think of it with anchors and clicks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly it!